# Проподает сглаживание текста при наклоне CSS

Tags: css3

Живой пример:

```css
.rotate {
/* Safari */
-webkit-transform: rotate(-5.0deg);

/* Firefox */
-moz-transform: rotate(-3.0deg);

/* IE */
-ms-transform: rotate(-3.0deg);

/* Opera */
-o-transform: rotate(-5.0deg);

/* Internet Explorer */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=5);

/* transform: rotate(-5.0deg); */
}

.rotate_02 {
transform: rotate(5.0deg); 
}
```

```html
<div class="rotate" style="width: 300px; font: normal 14px arial; margin-top: 12px; margin-left:18px;"><b style="color: #ff0000;">Внимание, вопрос!</b><br><span style="color: #666666;">Текст жутко теряет сглаживание. Чем это можно вылечить?</span></div>
<br>
<div class="rotate_02" style="width: 300px; font: normal 14px arial; margin-top: 12px; margin-left:18px;"><span style="color: #666666;">Или этот артефакт не поддаётся устранению на данном уровне развития и достижений технологий CSS?</span></div>
```

Исправимо это как-то или всё-таки нет?

Скрин: FireFox 55.0.3/OS Windows 7 64bit
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S.
Разобрался. Даже IE-11 справляется с сглаживанием корректно. Браузеры на движке Chromium: Opera, Google Chrome - справляются корректно. Значит имеет место быть недоработка самого движка FF, в плане рендера текста, если тот повёрнут средствами CSS.

Comment: Нашел в сети "css-трюки" сделал transform: perspective(1px); текс немного разлохматился. но это и придало ему какой-то тщедушный эффект сглаживания. Это как снять очки близорукому и будет эффект AA во всём. Неужели пока решение только это?